# React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create the [left hand menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMFXH.png) for my test application using react.

I am getting the following compilation error in the JSX of one of my classes.
Is it because I am not allowed to put html elements within the {} scripts in JSX? If so how can this be changed to make it work?

> ./src/components/LeftNav.js
>
> Line 10:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> Line 12:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

The component I am getting the error in is the following.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LeftNavItem from './LeftNavItem';

class LeftNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.leftNav.map((navItem) => {
                    <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>
                    navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
                        <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />
                        })
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default LeftNav;
```

Line 10 is

```
<li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>
```

Line 12 is

```
<LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />
```

The props for this class is

```
leftNav: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'System Admin',
        active: false,
        subMenu: [
          {
            id: 2,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            title: '',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            title: '',
            active: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        title: 'Reports',
        active: false,
        subMenu: [
          {
            id: 11,
            title: 'Reports',
            active: false
          },
          {
            id: 12,
            title: 'Dashboard',
            active: true
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            title: 'Templates',
            active: false
          }
        ]
```

LeftNavItem class is as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class LeftNavItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li><a href="">{this.props.navItem.title}</a></li>
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Cris, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ravibagul91 Thank you, that part is now working. I used react fragments like this <></>

Comment: What is the issue? have you seen the Demo?

Comment: @ravibagul91 Just saw the demo now. Thanks! Its all working now.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I tried to up vote your answer, but can only do that with higher reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using curly braces in the `map`s you need to explicitly use `return`. In addition, you'll also need to wrap your inner code in another element like a `div` or [a React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (which I've used here) as multiple children must be enclosed within a parent element.

```
<ul>
  {this.props.leftNav.map((navItem) => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>
        {navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
          return <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />
        })}
      </Fragment>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could replace those curly braces with parentheses and then the return is implied. You still need the parent element tho.

```
<ul>
  {this.props.leftNav.map((navItem) => (
    <Fragment>
      <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>
      {navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => (
        <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just forgot to return from `map`. You can use `Fragment` to wrap your outer `map` return.

```
{this.props.leftNav.map((navItem) => {
    return <React.Fragment key={navItem.id}>  //Provide key here
    <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>
    {navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
        //Here you should use subMenuItem
        return <LeftNavItem key={subMenuItem.id} navItem={subMenuItem} />  
      })
    }
    </React.Fragment>
})}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bstgcq)

**Note:** Read more about [`Keyed Fragments`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return values from `map`:

```
 {
  this.props.leftNav.map(navItem => {
    const navItems = navItem.subMenu.map(subMenuItem => {
      return <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />;
    });
    return (
      <>
        <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>;
        {navItems}
      </>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from your `map` function. You can wrap your content in parentheses instead of curly braces.

```
        <ul>
            {this.props.leftNav.map((navItem) => (
                <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}</li>
                navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
                    <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />
                    })
                })
            )
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple components to return then wrap them in a single HTMLElement or use `React Fragments`. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

On map you always have to return something.

Also wrap all your javascript code into **{}**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LeftNavItem from './LeftNavItem';

class LeftNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.leftNav.map((navItem) => {
                  return (
                    <li className="parent_wrapper">{navItem.title}
                    {navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
                        return <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem.subMenu} />
                        })}

                    </li>
                  )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default LeftNav;
```

Comment: You haven't wrapped the child elements in this example.